1970s or 1980s Movie Comedy About an Unpopular US President
I have been trying to search through Google and IMDB to find the name of a 1970's or 1980's movie comedy about an unpopular US President, but I haven't had any luck.
The scene that I can remember is The President driving his own limousine through the streets of an inner city. There is a mannequin of him up through the sun roof of the limo. A person on the street grabs a fruit or vegetable and throws it at the mannequin, hits it, and either it knocks the whole mannequin or the mannequins head off the car. 
I want to say that Bob Newhart might have played the president, but the one movie I found where he played the president, First Family, didn't sound like the plot was right.
I know this isn't much to go on, but if anyone remembers the scene and the movie that it comes from, I would appreciate the response.

Sounds a bit like Whoops Apocalypse!, but in that Loretta Swit played the President.
